# Is there still any top grandmaster who still regularly plays Queen's Gambit Accepted?

Tags: opening, queens-gambit-accepted

I believe Anand used to play QGA, but it seems like he stopped - presumably after losing several games to Kramnik with it.

Comment: Nowadays not really for any of the very top players.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of players who have been inside top ten it is Ponomariov who uses this opening the most often. Ivanchuk plays it too, but then again he plays most anything. And Nakamura played it a few times last year.

You can do searches for free online at 365chess.com.  Here is an example:
http://www.365chess.com/search_result.php?search=1&p=1&m=4&n=109&order=belo&ms=d4.d5.c4.dxc4&rev=&start=50